# Mark as read a specific notification in Laravel 5.3 Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know that there are many ways to mark as read all notifications of an User in L5.3 like this:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->unreadNotifications as $notification) {
    $notification->markAsRead();
}
```

Or:

```
$user->unreadNotifications->markAsRead();
```

But suppose I want to mark as read a specific notification with a given ID.

In fact, I have made a list of unread user notifications like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
        @foreach($AuthUser->unreadNotifications as $notif)
            <li>
                <a href="{{$notif->data['action']}}" data-notif-id="{{$notif->id}}">
                    {{$notif->data['message']}}
                </a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
</ul>
```

As you can see, each `a` tag has a `data-notif-id` attribute contain notif ID.

Now I want to send this ID to a script via Ajax (on click event) and mark as read that notification only. for that I wrote this:

```
$('a[data-notif-id]').click(function () {

        var notif_id   = $(this).data('notifId');
        var targetHref = $(this).data('href');

        $.post('/NotifMarkAsRead', {'notif_id': notif_id}, function (data) {
            data.success ? (window.location.href = targetHref) : false;
        }, 'json');

        return false;
});
```

`NotifMarkAsRead` refers to bellow Controller :

```
class NotificationController extends Controller
    {
        public function MarkAsRead (Request $request)
        {
              //What Do I do Here........
        }
    }
```

How can I do that while there is not any `Notification` Model?

Comment: If there's no `Notification` model (so, no relation set), where does the `unreadNotifications` method come from? Or: what is it? A custom method?

Comment: The `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait provides a `markAsRead` method and I used it in User Model.

Comment: `unreadNotifications()` returns a model, so could be you can use chaining to filter, like that: `$user->unreadNotifications()->where('notifications.id', $id)->markAsRead();`. Or, if the `markAsRead()` method is not available, I would also try to use `->update(['read_at' => Carbon::now()])` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this Answer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15277#issuecomment-244739160) on Github, solution is :

> `Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification` is where the Model for
>   the notifications exists, you can use it to grab a notification by ID
>   and delete it. Also if you don't want to use the model you can use a
>   normal DB query.

Comment: Exactly this answer what I was trying to find. Thanks for the model address.

Answer (score 14):

This works without fail:

```
$id = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications[0]->id;
auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('id', $id)->markAsRead();
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: this doesn't work if the notifications come from multiple models. You are assuming all notifications are user notifications, but notifications can be generated from any model

Answer (score 6):

```
$notification = auth()->user()->notifications()->find($notificationid);
if($notification) {
    $notification->markAsRead();
}
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: this doesn't work if the notifications come from multiple models. You are assuming all notifications are user notifications, but notifications can be generated from any model. Hence the OP asking about accessing notifications directly, NOT via the user model

Answer (score 1):

You must first make sure that the notification exists first so that you can make adjustments to it and I do not recommend using the unreadNotifications object because in the event that there are no unread notifications an error will occur because of that

```
$notification_id = "03fac369-2f41-43d0-bccb-e364aa645f8a";
$Notification = Auth::user()->Notifications->find($notification_id);
if($Notification){
   $Notification->markAsRead();
}
```

or you can directly edit without any check

```
DB::table('notifications')->where('id',$notification_id)->update(['read_at'=>Carbon::now()])
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked fine for me:

```
$unreadNotifications = Auth::user()->unreadNotifications()->whereIn('id', $items)->get();
```

where $items is an array of notifications' ids!

Answer (score -3):

Instead of the following :

```
$user->unreadNotifications->markAsRead();
```

let's use :

```
$user->unreadNotifications->first()->markAsRead();
```

Comment: While this approach allows for marking ONE unread notification as read, it doesn't really give you the option to control which notification it is. using `firstWhere` or any of the solutions above is a better option.